# Derivative of the derivative of a function with respect to the function itself

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

While in the middle of solving a differential equation. I stumbled upon this expression I need to expand 
and process more:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial f}\left( f^\prime + f \right)
$$

Having $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, and $f^\prime = \frac{df}{dt}$.

With regards to this expression:

$$
\frac{\partial f^\prime}{\partial f}
$$

What exactly does this expression evaluates to?

Comment: is $\ f=f(t) $?

Comment: @ManjoyDas It is not $\frac{\partial f^\prime}{\partial t}$. We are not extracting the first order derivative of the derivative by $t$, but by $f$

Comment: What i asked is whether $\ f$ is a function of one variable or more than one variables.

Comment: If $\ f$ is a function of one variable then $\ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$ reduces to $\ \dfrac{d}{dx}$. But you didnot mention any variable other than $\ t$. And if it is a function of more than one variable, then you can't differentiate w.r.t a function.

Answer (score 1):

Since the wording of the question doesn't specify what are the variables in the function $f$ and that a variable $(t)$ is mentioned, one supposes that there is only one variable. So the equation is not a PDE but is an ODE.

If this supposition is not true, the problem is ill-posed.

If the supposition is true  :
$$
\frac{d}{df}\left( f^\prime + f \right)=$$
$$=\frac{d}{df}\left( \frac{df}{dt} + f \right)=$$
$$=\left(\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{df}{dt} + f \right)\right)\frac{dt}{df}=$$
$$=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{df}{dt} + f \right)}{\frac{df}{dt}}=$$
$$=\frac{ \frac{d^2f}{dt^2} + \frac{df}{dt} }{\frac{df}{dt}}=$$
$$=\frac{ \frac{d^2f}{dt^2}}{\frac{df}{dt}}+1$$

Comment: JJacquelin: Thanks for your answer. I am reading it but it seems exactly what I was looking for. A comment though about your first statements on my question. If you read it, you will see that I did specify the nature of $f$ and its signature, therefore you know that it is a real-valued function of a real variable. Also, the expression under differentiation can be differentiated on different quantities, therefore I used the $\partial$ sign. Again thanks or the answer.

Comment: I think that one have to make a difference between "variable" and "parameter". In the written equation only one variable is involved in the differentiation. Of course one or  many parameters can be also present but they are not variables in the differentiation.

Comment: I see your point... yeah it is always kinda tricky. This problem I have here raised from a bigger one involving the Euler-Lagrange method. In there, the problem formulation uses $\partial$ on $F(x, y, y^\prime)$ ($x$ the variable on which function $y(x)$ depends on) to indicate differentiation with respect to $y$ and $y^\prime$... so it's kinda tricky eheh

Comment: OK.  $F$ being defined as $F(x,y,y')$ this is a function with several variables and in this context I agree with the symbol $\partial$.

Comment: Ah I see your point... so since $F$ reports the three expressions it depends on ($y$ and its derivative are not exactly variables) in the parentheses, even though in the end, the final expression of $F$ depends solely on $x$, we can see $y$ and $y^\prime$ as variables. :)